# Different CA cert per endpoint vs Proxy

Tags: ssl, nginx, proxy, man-in-the-middle

I have been running a small REST API back end that has the following two endpoints.

- `/panel` (Site administration, has UI)
- `/api/v1` (JSON API)

There is no user facing front end, the API simply caters to a mobile app. Access to the entire back end (*all endpoints*) is secured by a single self signed client certificate and nginx as the reverse proxy.

I now need to add another user(with his own login credentials) who will be able to perform certain CRUD operations on the back end through the administration panel at `/panel`. This will require me to share a client certificate with him(I guess PFX would be most convenient) for browser access to the `/panel` endpoint.

Pardon my weak knowledge of SSL, but is it actually possible for a malicious vendor to MITM my app with a client certificate which is different from the one being used in the app, but issued by the same CA(my own)?

If so, I guess I have two options, either setting up different CA's for different endpoints on nginx or looking at setting up a light weight proxy for my back end.

Which approach would you recommend? If I choose to go with a free, light weight proxy for vendor access that I can use to add SSL information to the incoming requests from the vendor, are there any suggestions?

Comment: If you control the CA no one can create a certificate signed by this CA (as long as the private key is protected). A certificate is signed by another certificate, like the CA one, and this signature uses the private key of the signing certificate.

Comment: Assuming I issue a second client certificate signed by my private CA and send it over to someone to enable web access, can they use the client certificate (and key, since I will be packaging both in a PFX) to sniff on my app traffic? The app uses a different client certificate, issued by the same CA. My nginx is set up to verify the CA for the client certificate.

Comment: Each TLS transaction is secured separately from others, and if you are using modern enough ciphers enabled Perfect Forward Secrecy even after the fact for a given certificate having the certificate won't allow to decrypt the traffic exchanged with it (because the encryption keys are generated at beginning of handshake and are completely transient, they are not the certificate private key).